# UI From Service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I'm trying to start an activity from a service and can't get the screen to turn on.
The background service runs every 5 minutes.
Here's the call:
**Service**

```
 private boolean criticalAlarm(int inBg, int inAlarmType) {
        Intent openAlarmActivity = new Intent(this, MySwipeAlarm.class);
        openAlarmActivity.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        openAlarmActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        openAlarmActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

        openAlarmActivity.putExtra("bgValue", String.valueOf(inBg));
        openAlarmActivity.putExtra("alarmType", String.valueOf(inAlarmType));
        if(glbDebug) Log.d("DexService", "Starting Critical alarm activity");
        startActivity(openAlarmActivity);
        return true;
    }
```

And here's the start of the activity.

```
public class MySwipeAlarm extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    //declare variables
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    final DexDB myDb    = new DexDB(this);
    ...
```

**Some notes**. The 'debug' statement below *does* get invoked. If I call some media player, it gets called, so it's not a power manager situation (which is handled in the service) and not a manifest issue. I've been struggling with this for a while, and ***I just cannot get the screen to turn on***.

NOTE2: The attempt to turn the screen on via the getWindow doesn't work in the method below or if specified during onCreate()..

```
  @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow(){

        if(debug) Log.d("Alarm", "HERE ????");
        Window window = getWindow();

        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |                       // Let's wake up the screen
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION  |                                  // hide nav bar
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |                                  // hide nav bar
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |                                        // hide status bar
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

    }
```

**Part of the manifest**

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

and some output just to prove that "stuff" is getting called

```
04-16 14:43:09.121 1131-1131/com.dextender.dextender D/Alarm: Past starting the screen
04-16 14:43:09.131 1131-1131/com.dextender.dextender D/Typeface: fontPath: 
04-16 14:43:09.131 1131-1131/com.dextender.dextender D/SQLiteConnection: enable sqlite enhance.
04-16 14:43:09.151 1131-1131/com.dextender.dextender D/Alarm: HERE ????
04-16 14:43:09.161 1131-1231/com.dextender.dextender E/OpenGLRenderer: void android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::setSurface(android::Surface *) to create EGLSurface com.dextender.dextender/com.dextender.dextender.MySwipeAlarm
04-16 14:43:09.171 1131-1131/com.dextender.dextender D/Typeface: fontPath: 
04-16 14
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and I'm sharing, since my searches turned up very little on the subject.

Note: it's 2018, so some information I found is old.

My service spawns an activity, and the wakelock is handled in the service. Old posts about doing full wake locks are no longer applicable since its been deprecated, so screen on/off manipulation must be done via the WindowManager.

So, the service gets the partial wakelock, fires the intent and everything at this point is in the hands of the activity.

Issue 1 - was that in the "OnPause" was calling destroy, because I wanted to kill the alarm if someone pressed the home button. Issue there was that the screen never turned on, which then called OnPause, and the activity was terminated.

Issue 2 - The real crux of the problem was in the difference between addflags and setFlags in the getWindow() calls. I had setFlags, without specifying "FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON" (duh!). If you look at my original post, I have it as a mask to setFlags. I changed the call to:

```
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |                       // Let's wake up the screen
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

and this fixed the issue.

I did move the above call to the onAttachedToWindow() method instead of onCreate(), and put back the call to destroy on the "onPause()" method.

This was tested with the phone OFF and lock screen on, and also when the phone was ON, but a different application in the foreground before my app took over.

Lesson learned. When copy/pasting examples, understand how they work.